# Do I need to know Python to use OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I need to use OPenCV for a project. My question is do I need to know Python before I can use OpenCV? (FYI, I am not fit in C/C++)

Comment: You need to know any one language. visit www.opencvpython.blogspot.com for details on programming OpenCV with Python.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you do. Other choice is **C/C++**.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find best results using C/C++. As far as I know it only has libraries for Python or C/C++. Maybe Java? In any case,  you will need to know whatever language you choose in order to work with it. It is a set of libraries, not a standalone language.